# Минимальная версия для Google maps

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Хотелось бы узнать, с какой версии `API` можно встраивать гугл карты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps API v2 можно использовать с API level 8 (Froyo 2.2). Вот [здесь об этом говорят](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024040/minimal-android-api-level-to-run-google-maps-android-api-v2). А с каких пор можно использовать первую версию уже, наверное, никто не помнит.

Само приложение Google Maps есть в Андроиде с самой первой версии. Видимо тогда и стало можно.